# Why can't my android application find Text View or Buttons declared in the XML file?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I was following the tutorials online on Android Programming using Eclipse by New Boston and I am stuck at a particular point. So,everything was working fine, I had a button and a TextView in my GUI interface. Now, when i went to my java file and tried to locate it by using the R.Id..... it can't recognize the Button id or TextView Id declared in the XML file. Why am i getting this error? Can someone please correct my mistake. I am using Minimum SDK - API8- Android 2.2 ,Target SDK-API 13-Android 3.2 and Compiling with SDK- API 19- Android 4.4.

I checked the following article on Stack Overflow [My Android application cannot find buttons declared in the XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750714/my-android-application-cannot-find-buttons-declared-in-the-xml-file). As per the solution, I should delete the imports android.R from my java file and i dont have that import at all. So, i am kind of confused.

Main Activity.java

```
package com.example.androidprogram1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView display;
    Button show;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        show = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

//Error message:- Create field Button1 in type id (Suggestions) /create Constant TextView1 in type id.....This is the error i get. It seems that the id of the button and textView is not adding to the R.java file

```
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tvView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.androidprogram1.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks a lot.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `TextView` and `Button`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}
```

Edit: Your error message seems to be an Eclipse problem, rather than something you've done, unless you went in and made changes to `R.java`, which you shouldn't do. Save your project, close it, re-open and re-build it. Also, if you happen to have `import android.R` in your class, remove it.

Comment: :- Create field Button1 in type id (Suggestions) /create Constant TextView1 in type id.....This is the error i get. It seems that the id of the button and textView is not adding to the R.java file. What do i do?

Comment: @MissyZewdie See the edit. Your error seems to be an Eclipse bug.

Comment: :- So, i tried adding another button to my GUI and the same error showed up and then i close eclipse and restarted it again and the error disappeared. So, how do i fix this error permanently because its irritating to keep restarting eclipse everytime i make changes in my GUI.

Comment: @MissyZewdie Does this problem occur every name you add a new item to your layout? Cleaning and building the project is needed every time?

Comment: :- Yeah literally every time and i am so addicted to eclipse that i cant ignore it. Its my first love!

Comment: @MissyZewdie - If you keep having problems like this, do a `clean build` on your project in eclipse. The errors should disappear.